# Keras Conv1D steps parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I'm building a natural network and I don't understand the input dimensions of Conv1D. The parameters are batch, steps, channels, and I'm using to_categorical so my data fits this input shape. I'm just not sure if I'm using the correct input. It's currently batch, features, to_categorical array. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The below example code should hopefully clarify how to use the Conv1D, and the meaning of the dimensions.  As a reminder, in Keras usually the batch/sample dimension is not specified when defining the model.  It is inferred automatically from the actual input data.  That's why you don't see "num_samples" used until the x_train and y_train are defined.  I hope this helps.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

num_output_units = 4
num_time_steps = 10
num_features = 6
num_samples = 20

myInput = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(num_time_steps, num_features))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_output_units, kernel_size=3, padding='same')(myInput)
final_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

myModel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=myInput, outputs=final_output)

# display the model architecture
print(myModel.summary())

# Input data
x_train = np.random.random((num_samples, num_time_steps, num_features))

# Target/label data
y_train = np.random.random((num_samples, num_time_steps, 1))

myModel.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')

# train the model
myModel.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2)

myModel.predict(x_train)
```

Comment: That's fairly useful, my main question is where would time_steps be defined if a 2x2 dataframe was used? It has rows and columns, so where would the extra dimension be from?